# Domain refers to the local machine

Tags: dns, ping, host

Just was walking around till I tried to ping a domain .
But I surprised that it was the domain of the localhost !

I went to see what the wrong was , and how this domain set itself .

However,I didn't find anything that related to it in the localhost OS !

I tried to ping it via online ping service , and the surprise is here , it pings the localhost of the service host !

The domain is :

```
securitytube.com
```

Is there any explanation ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A. For questions like this about basic Internet services, you might want to head over to http://SuperUser.com. I'm voting to close this question, as it's off-topic for StackOverflow. Incidentally, you'd likely have to ask the owners of the domain in question why they've set up their DNS the way they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be migrated to [superuser](https://superuser.com/) but the answer to your question is because the owners of that domain have an IP address of `0.0.0.0` set...

```
$host securitytube.com
securitytube.com has address 0.0.0.0
securitytube.com mail is handled by 0 mail.happyisp.com.

$ping securitytube.com
PING securitytube.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
```

Most linux boxes will presume that's the loop-back address (Hence return 127.0.0.1) Windows boxes appear to not do anything other than error out.

```
c:\ping 0.0.0.0
Pinging 0.0.0.0 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```